# Cygwin ratfiv installation

Tags: cygwin

Thank's to Mike I succeded install ratfor for cygwin.

Now, I want to install ratfiv. I have untar the pacakge and when I launch the command

```
make
```

I have this message:

```
g77 -v -g -fno-globals -c ratfiv.f
Utilisation des specs internes.
COLLECT_GCC=g77
g77: erreur: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-globals’
```

Here it's the file I tried to compile

```
# Makefile to build xratfiv from fortran files
# Ratfor character is defined as INTEGER. (see README).
# N. Brouard January 1996.
# If succeed, you can bootstrap with ../Makefile.
FORTC= g77
CFLAGS= -v -g -fno-globals
# For ULTRIX
#FORTC= f77
#CFLAGS= -v -g 
# For AIX
#FORTC= xlf 
LFLAGS= -v -g

ratfiv: ratfiv.o support.o io.o opn.o gtarg.o xitstat.o
$(FORTC) $(LFLAGS) -o ratfiv ratfiv.o support.o io.o opn.o gtarg.o xitstat.o
ratfiv.o: ratfiv.f
$(FORTC) $(CFLAGS) -c ratfiv.f
support.o: support.f
$(FORTC) $(CFLAGS) -c support.f
io.o:  io.f
$(FORTC) $(CFLAGS) -c io.f
xitstat.o:  xitstat.f
$(FORTC) $(CFLAGS) -c xitstat.f
opn.o:  opn.f
$(FORTC) $(CFLAGS) -c opn.f
gtarg.o: gtarg.f
$(FORTC) $(CFLAGS) -c gtarg.f

clean:
rm -f *.o *.lst xratfiv
```

When I removed the -fno-globals option, the file ratfiv.exe is generated but do not work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When I launch

```
ratfiv
```

I have nothing while if I launch ratfor I have:

```
C Output from Public domain Ratfor, version 1.0
```

Maybe it's normal I don't know because I don't use those programms, I'm just computer scientist.

Comment: Is this an answer of some kind, or were you trying to edit your question?

Comment: Both pak. I haven't seen I could add a comment instead of reply or best to edit my first post. Sorry.